# Remote Desktop Connection, how do you disable it on domain?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote

Basically, I don't want my server accessible via the primary domain (which is shared with the primary IP).  Is there a way I can block it via the domain but allow it directly on the IP only? Or even setting up the domain as "domain.com/rdc_1010 that will route to that port?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 would the OS

Comment: Why not use the internal Firewall of Windows? Block in Domain the RDP Port and activate it for other ips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing RDP via name or ip address still connects to the same port on the server.  What you're wanting is for dns to not resolve when the rdp client uses the name, and it just doesn't work that way.  If you want to make it a little more secured, then consider changing the rdp port on the server to something other than the default of 3389.  You could also consider using the Windows Firewall on the server to block connections except for allowed ip addresses as well.

Comment: This is true; but I didn't want to use the "allow ip addresses" since I could be on any network.  But I think the idea of changing the port would probably work the best. Thanks!

Comment: Here you go.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759